# Finding the best matching sequence

Tags: python, hamming-distance

I have 2 files of sequences. Say ham1.txt :

```
AAACCCTTTGGG
AGGTACTTTTTT
TCTCTTTTTTTT
```

and so on

ham2.txt:

```
AAACCCTTTGGG
GAGAGGGAGGGC
AGGTACTTTTTT
CTCTTAATTTCC
TCTCTTTTTTTT
GTTTTTAAAAAA
```

I want to match sequences in ham1.txt to those in ham2.txt depending on which pair has the minumum Hamming distance. The python code I have prints Hamming distance between all of them. I just want the best matched pair. Here is my code

```
def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    #Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

with open('ham1.txt','r') as file1:
                for s1 in file1:
                        with open('ham2.txt','r') as file2:
                                for s2 in file2:
                                        dist = hamming_distance(s1,s2)
                                        print s1,s2,dist
```

Can you suggest edits. Thanks

Comment: `scipy.spatial.distance.hamming()` already exists in scipy.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at `itertools.product`:

```
In [7]:

L1 = ['AAACCCTTTGGG',
      'AGGTACTTTTTT',
      'TCTCTTTTTTTT']
L2 = ['AAACCCTTTGGG',
      'GAGAGGGAGGGC',
      'AGGTACTTTTTT',
      'CTCTTAATTTCC',
      'TCTCTTTTTTTT',
      'GTTTTTAAAAAA']
def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    #Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))
import itertools
res = [[hamming_distance(*item), item[0], item[1]] for item in itertools.product(L1, L2)]
sorted(res)[0]
Out[7]:
[0, 'AAACCCTTTGGG', 'AAACCCTTTGGG']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have generated the following list

```
0 AAACCCTTTGGG AAACCCTTTGGG
0 AGGTACTTTTTT AGGTACTTTTTT
0 TCTCTTTTTTTT TCTCTTTTTTTT
6 AGGTACTTTTTT TCTCTTTTTTTT
6 TCTCTTTTTTTT AGGTACTTTTTT
7 AAACCCTTTGGG AGGTACTTTTTT
7 AGGTACTTTTTT AAACCCTTTGGG
8 AAACCCTTTGGG TCTCTTTTTTTT
8 AGGTACTTTTTT CTCTTAATTTCC
8 TCTCTTTTTTTT AAACCCTTTGGG
8 TCTCTTTTTTTT CTCTTAATTTCC
9 AAACCCTTTGGG GAGAGGGAGGGC
9 TCTCTTTTTTTT GTTTTTAAAAAA
10 AAACCCTTTGGG CTCTTAATTTCC
11 AGGTACTTTTTT GAGAGGGAGGGC
11 AGGTACTTTTTT GTTTTTAAAAAA
12 AAACCCTTTGGG GTTTTTAAAAAA
12 TCTCTTTTTTTT GAGAGGGAGGGC
```

I guess that is what your need, right?

To achieve this  have used a couple of liberies.
First I convert the datastream/strings into lists of values, then I take every poosible
combination of `ham1` and `ham2`, and create a new list also holding the hamming value,
and then I sort them.

Is this helping you? Otherwise just ask I will help you out ;)

The code used is below.

```
from distance import hamming
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

ham1="""
AAACCCTTTGGG
AGGTACTTTTTT
TCTCTTTTTTTT
"""

ham2="""
AAACCCTTTGGG
GAGAGGGAGGGC
AGGTACTTTTTT
CTCTTAATTTCC
TCTCTTTTTTTT
GTTTTTAAAAAA
"""

ham1data = filter(None, ham1.splitlines())
ham2data = filter(None, ham2.splitlines())

res = [(hamming(h1,h2), h1, h2) for h1, h2, in product(ham1data, ham2data)]

for v, h1, h2 in sorted(res):
    print v, h1, h2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce


def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    #Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('h1.txt') as f:
        f1 = f.read().splitlines()

    with open('h2.txt') as f:
        f2 = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in f1:
        print(line, reduce(lambda x, y: x if hamming_distance(line, y) > hamming_distance(line, x) else y, f2))
```

Output:

```
AAACCCTTTGGG AAACCCTTTGGG
AGGTACTTTTTT AGGTACTTTTTT
TCTCTTTTTTTT TCTCTTTTTTTT
```